# How should I change the value of a parameter using the event listener?

Tags: symfony

Very short question: I wonder if the best way to change the value of a parameter passed into an event is by passing it by reference? I'm a bit hesitated to do this for some reason, just feel like something is wrong here but not sure what is.

Some sample code as requested:

```
class CoreEvent extends \Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Event
{
    /**
     * @var storing the current page content
     */
    private $content;

    /**
     * sets content
     *
     * @param $content
     */
    public function setContent($content)
    {
        $this->content = $content;
    } 

    /**
     * gets content
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getContent()
    {
        return $this->content;        
    }

}
```

Setup the event

```
$core_event= new CoreEvent();
$content = "some content";
$core_event->setContent($content);
```

Below is the sample listener code:

```
$this->eventDispatcher->addListener("onPageEnd", array($this, 'onPageEnd'));
```

Dispatcher:

```
$container->get('event_dispatcher')->dispatch("onPageEnd", $core_event);
```

Now say if I want the functions called by the dispatcher (assuming many listeners to be listening to this same event) to be able to change/modify the $content, there seems to be 2 ways:

1. The first method is to change the content, then use setContent defined above to set the content back to the event
2. The second method is to pass the content by reference instead (we will have to modify setContent and getContent abit to set and get by content)

Comment: Show some of your code, please.

Comment: I added some sample code as requested

Comment: 1st method is the common one.  Its ok if you will set new content with setContent method call.